# First value has distribution $[-5; 0]$, second $[0; 2]$. What is the probability their sum is in $[-1; 1]$?

Tags: calculus, probability

Given two uniformly distributed values, how do I find the probability their sum belongs to some interval?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: If two variables are both uniformly (and independently) distributed on intervals, their combination is uniformly distributed in a rectangle in the plane. Which rectangle is that, and what part of the rectangle corresponds to their sum being between $-1$ and $1$?